# pass 2d BOOL c array to function as parameter

Tags: ios, objective-c

Hi i am developing iOS application. I have created BOOL array in one function of my class like

```
-(void)functionOne
{
  BOOL array[10][10];
}
```

I want this array to be passed in another function of same class say as `functionTwo` as parameter

How can i do this? I searched a lot but did not find any workable solution.

Comment: why don't you declare your array in your class interface?

Comment: You want to pass it as a parameter from functionOne to functionTwo ?

Comment: Jerome Diaz i want to do some calculations and then want to decalare array in that function like BOOL array[height][width]. I wont do it in class interface

Comment: giorashc YES i want to pass it as parameter to other function

Comment: probably worth reading an introductory guide to C programming

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't get your requirement. But just try the code given,

```
- (BOOL *)function1 {

    static BOOL array[10][10];

    return &array[0][0];
}

- (void)function2:(BOOL *)array {


}
```

From the same class you can invoke method like

```
[self function2:[self function1]];
```

Just try this :)